# converting URI to URL using python

Tags: python, url, uri, printers, pycups

I have a list of printers and I got their URI using pycups. now I need to know their IP addresses and to do that, I need to know their URL. How can I convert those URIs to URLs?
for example, I have this 
URI: dnssd://HP%20LaserJet%20M402dn%20(0988D9)-0._ipp._tcp.local/ 
And I need to know the ip address of my printer. how can I do it? when I use socket.gethostbyaddr() to find it, I get an exception that name or service not known

Comment: Maybe you could give us some more informations ? And a little bit example code what you are trying ? As far a in know URL is a subset of URI so every URL is a URI ?

Comment: for example, I have this URI: dnssd://HP%20LaserJet%20M402dn%20(0988D9)-0._ipp._tcp.local/   And I need to know the ip address of my printer. how can I do it? when I use socket.gethostbyaddr() to find it, I get and exception that name or service not known

Comment: Please, add information as needed or asked for into your question, not just comments.